# a middle approach between Dynamic Typing and Static Typing

Tags: dynamic, types, binding, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I wanted to ask if anyone knows of a programming language where there is dynamic typing but the binding between a name and a type is permanent. Static typing guards your code from assigning a wrong value into a variable, but forces you to declare(and know) the type before compilation. Dynamic typing allows you to assign values with a different type to the same variable one after the other. What I was thinking is, it would be nice to have dynamic typing, but once the variable is bound, the first binding also determines the type of the variable.
For example, using python-like syntax, if I write by mistake:

persons = []
....
adam = Person("adam")
persons = adam      #(instead of persons += [adam])

Then I want to get an error(either at runtime or during compilation if possible) because name was defined as a list, and cannot accept values of type Person.
Same thing if the type can not be resolved statically:

result = getData()
...
result = 10

Will generate a runtime error iff getData() did not return an integer. 
I know you can hack a similar behavior with a wrapper class but it would be nice to have the option by default in the language as I don't see a good legitimate use for this flexibility in dynamic languages(except for inheritance, or overwriting a common default value such as null/None which could be permitted as special cases).